# spring Webclient generics Result<Lead>.class not work

Tags: spring, generics, mono, spring-webclient

in spring webclient i want deserialize response in Result

'''

```
Mono<Result<Lead>> result = webClient
        .get()
        .uri("/leads?page="+page)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Bearer " + tocken)
        .retrieve().bodyToMono(Result<Lead>.class);
```

'''
Result.class return error

can how i use generics in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Spring doesn't know about the generic type it deserializes any unknown type to LinkedHashMap.So use **ParameterizedTypeReference** to deserialize the json to the exact type of Result. The **ParameterizedTypeReference** capture the generic type and retain it at runtime.

```
Mono<Result<Lead>> result = webClient
    .get()
    .uri("/leads?page="+page)
    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Bearer " + tocken)
   .retrieve().bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Result<Lead>>(){
    });;
```